# What is this video format, and how do I convert It

Tags: video, encoding, codec, h.264

### Description

I have a big (7.4G) .mkv file (1080p) which I want to convert to H.264 (using x264)

### Problem

1. MediaCoder and GSpot are unable to detect the codec. They don't display anything. Just that the file is a matroska Container Video with a MIMEtype of video/x-matroska. No bitrate, profile etc.
2. But the source tells me that is VC-1 encoded.

### Question

So how do I encode this file. as in, using what encoding software, since MediaCoder has failed.

Comment: Can VLC play it?

Comment: no, it just plays the audio. only media player classic does. I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matroska is just a "container" format.  You can use any sort of video and audio compression for the streams stored in it.

You can convert Matroska files with VLC (http://www.videolan.org), ffmpeg (http://www.ffmpeg.org), and mencoder (http://www.mplayerhq.hu)

Comment: I'll try the first two as Mencoder was failing at doing the job.

Comment: VLC has been the best Matroska player I have found.  Since it will convert as well I would assume that it will be able to handle your job.

Answer (score 0):

.mkv  = matroska Video, .mka  = matroska Audio, .mks = matroska Subtitle

There's a couple encoder/decoder who can handle it. Of the hand, I'd say MeGui, Total Video Converter or VirtualDubMod.

I'm not sure though about the first two, but VirtualDubMod should be able to handle it, seeing as it is a modded VirtualDub JUST for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

**[SUPER © Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer.](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)**

> A GUI to FFmpeg, MEncoder, MPlayer,
>   **x264**, musepack, monkey's audio, true
>   audio, wavpack, ffmpeg2theora and the
>   theora/vorbis RealProducer plugIn.

SUPER © will **convert any** VOB, ASF, AVI, MPG, RM, OGG, **MKV**, MOV, MP4, WMV etc.. with a single click.

*SUPER is freeware.*

Comment: That looks awfully spammy.

Comment: i know, the website is sheer disgrace, but the program is most certainly the best unversal ancoder there is.

Comment: +1 for a spammy and horrid website... they aren't doing themselves any favors. I won't be surprised if it asks for me to sign up for a dating site as part of the download process.